# Scala.js - Handling NaN

Tags: scala.js

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.Date
import org.scalajs.dom.window.alert

val num: Double = new Date("a").getTime
alert((num + 1).toString)
```

This code reports `NaN` as the value of the alert. How do I know beforehand that `num` is a `NaN` in Scala.js code and not a proper `Double`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood the question, you can test for `NaN` with the `isNaN` method:

```
if (num.isNaN)
  println("it is NaN")
```